# java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I have a dockerized Spark instance and use SJS to submit spark jobs from my Spring boot application. 
Everything worked fine so far but now I get the following exception when submitting a job as per the sjs log.

```
Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file /tmp/spark-f6f7e14c-0d89-40b0-b2d8-262278b619db/blockmgr-1eaf0f4d-8451-4eda-a2e3-ca3acafab871/09/temp_shuffle_c8e20306-d111-49b2-b025-d47ba7cac723
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.truncate(FileChannelImpl.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.revertPartialWritesAndClose(BlockObjectWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$stop$2.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:807)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter$$anonfun$stop$2.apply(ExternalSorter.scala:806)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.stop(ExternalSorter.scala:806)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.stop(SortShuffleWriter.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm running Docker for mac 1.13 beta and I have enough space on the disk.
Thanks for any information related to this.